# How to use a variable outside of a function

Tags: swift, function, variables

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SuccessMark.maximumValue = 100
    SuccessMark.value = successMark
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let successMark = SuccessMark.value
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incorrectly posted, and there is not a specific question describing what you are trying to do and what is happening in your code.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new at this. I'm trying to access the variable successMark in viewDidLoad(). In the line SuccessMark.value = successMark I get the error :  Use of unresolved identifier 'successMark'. I get why but I get the error but I don't know how use the variable successMark outside of the function viewDidDissapear.

Comment: It's called a few things. Variable scope for starters. Declare variables needed outside of a single function outside of said function!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable in the viewcontroller class, outside of any functions. This way the whole viewcontroller class will be able to read and write to/from the variable.

```
Class ViewController: UIViewController {

var successMark: YourCustomType! // either initialise it empty or use optionals as needed, YourCustomType! or YourCustomType?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    SuccessMark.maximumValue = 100
    SuccessMark.value = successMark
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        successMark = SuccessMark.value
   }
}
```